# Pandas - check if a value has appeared in previous rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column in DataFrame that looks like this:

| Col1 |
| --- |
| A |
| B |
| A |
| C |
| B |

I want to add a boolean column that indicates for each row whether the value in that row has appeared in the **previous** rows. The desired output would look like this:

| Col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | True |
| B | True |
| A | False |
| C | True |
| B | False |

How can I achieve it? I've tried `window.expanding()` with `isin()`, but it appears to apply to numeric columns only (mine contains strings only).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) with invert mask by `~`, alterntive solution is use [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://%5Bandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) with specify column name:

```
df['col2'] = ~df['Col1'].duplicated()
#alternative solution
#df['col2'] = ~df.duplicated('Col1')

print (df)
  Col1   col2
0    A   True
1    B   True
2    A  False
3    C   True
4    B  False
```

**Details**:

```
print (df['Col1'].duplicated())
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
Name: Col1, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) and invert the result with `~`:

```
df['col2'] = ~df['Col1'].duplicated()
```

output:

```
  Col1   col2
0    A   True
1    B   True
2    A  False
3    C   True
4    B  False
```